# Javascript/jQuery, Display div after animation finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YnT2X/

I don't want the div to display until AFTER the return animation completes.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu").hover(function () {
        $('#arrow').hide();
        $("body").children(':not(#menu)').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(2px)");
        $(this, '#arrow').stop().animate({
            width: "200px"
        }, 250,

        function () {
            if ($('#menu').width() == '200') {
                $('.text').fadeIn(200);
            }
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, 250)
        $("body").children(':not(#menu)').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
        $('.text').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#arrow').show();
    });
    });
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but is this it -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/YnT2X/1/) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upycZ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu").hover(function () {
        $('#arrow').hide();
        $("body").children(':not(#menu)').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(2px)");
        $(this, '#arrow').stop().animate({
            width: "200px"
        }, 250,

        function () {
            if ($('#menu').width() == '200') {
                $('.text').fadeIn(200);
            }
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, 250,function(){
        $('#arrow').show(); //<- Shows arrow after run
        });
        $("body").children(':not(#menu)').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
        $('.text').fadeOut('fast');

    });
});
```

Comment: No Problem :). If you have found this useful can you please mark it as the answer by checking off the checkmark to the left of this post?